# Pass multiple params array into method

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I have a `GenericRepository` with this function:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
    Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
    int? Page=0,
    params Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>[] filter)
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;

    if (filter != null)
    {
        foreach (var z in filter)
        {
            query = query.Where(z);
        }

    }
    if (orderBy != null)
    {
        return orderBy(query).ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        return query.ToList();
    }
}
```

In one of my controllers I need also use include clauses so I decided to create new class `DeviceInstanceRepository` which will inherit `GenericRepository` and create new `GetFiltered` method and i got something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<DeviceInstance> GetFiltered(
    Func<IQueryable<DeviceInstance>, IOrderedQueryable<DeviceInstance>> orderBy = null, 
    int? Page = 0, 
    **WhatTypeShouldIUSeHere?** System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<DeviceInstance,bool>>[] include ,
    params System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<DeviceInstance, bool>>[] filter)
{
    IQueryable<DeviceInstance> query = dbSet;

    if(include!=null)
    {
        foreach(var z in include)
        {
            query = query.Include(z);
        }
    }
    if (filter != null)
    {
        foreach (var z in filter)
        {
            query = query.Where(z);
        }
    }
    if (orderBy != null)
    {
        return orderBy(query).ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        return query.ToList();
    }
}
```

But I have problems with parameters type. **I know I can't pass two params array**. Can you suggest me how to modify this line:

```
params System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<DeviceInstance,bool>>[] include ,
```

to make things working?

Comment: You cannot use params twice in the same function, it's not c# comply

Comment: As I wrote in my question. That's I'm asking how to modify my code. To some kind of array instead or what

Comment: I would keep a separate common part, then use three function signatures.

Comment: @szpic You're trying to `override` method without keeping the same set of parameters? That's not gonna work. And btw. to make your first `Get` method work, you should pass `orderBy` as `Expression<Func<...>>`. Otherwise ordering will be performed as LINQ to Objects query, what is not really a good way to go.

Comment: Thanks Now I see that my attempt was completely wrong. Btw pozdrowienia z aei ;)

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek - as far as I see, he is not overriding that method, he is adding new one, with different name.

Comment: @SergeyS he updated the question after my comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve using such approach, but if you strongly want to pass two `params` parameters in your method, you can merge them into one `params`, just need also pass number of one of them. Like this (notice `Take` and `Skip` there):

```
    public IEnumerable<DeviceInstance> GetFiltered(
        Func<IQueryable<DeviceInstance>, IOrderedQueryable<DeviceInstance>> orderBy = null, 
        int? Page = 0,
        int numberOfIncludeExpressions = 0,
        params System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<DeviceInstance, bool>>[] expressions)
    {
        IQueryable<DeviceInstance> query = dbSet;

        if (expressions != null)
        {
            foreach (var z in expressions.Take(numberOfIncludeExpressions))
            {
                query = query.Include(z);
            }

            foreach (var z in expressions.Skip(numberOfIncludeExpressions))
            {
                query = query.Where(z);
            }
        }
        if (orderBy != null)
        {
            return orderBy(query).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            return query.ToList();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately include and where can not be in the same array because they have different return types bool and IQueryable<>

Comment: Then it would be best to split this logic into two different methods.